# Is there a good tutorial on setting up the Augustus PMML scoring engine as a web service?

Tags: python, r

I know it is possible, but the provided documentation here:

http://code.google.com/p/augustus/

is thin.

The documentation for setting up the web service states:

"Configuring the Augustus PMML consumer is covered in great detail elsewhere so we will limit our discussion to what is needed to get the consumer to accept data via HTTP, namely the fromHTTP child element of inputData."

The problem is that "in great detail elsewhere" isn't in great enough detail for me, i.e., I'm looking for something kind of "hello world"-ish.

Comment: Have you already gone over the Augustus walkthrough?

http://174.129.21.118/augustus/Tutorial/build/html/

Comment: @C8H10N4O2 - I have no idea.  My comment was from 5 years ago!  Will delete it now! :o